# Why doesn't the module show images?

Tags: 8

I am trying to use the **drupal_slider** module (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_slider) in a clean, just installed Drupal 8.8.5 because it may provide a way to overlay text over the image.

Setup:

1. Created a content type called "Slide" w/Title, Body and Image.
2. Created 4 slides with images
3. Modified Media > Drupal Slider to add a Slide and Slide Group
4. Created a View that almost looks exactly like the sample on the module page

   - Format: Drupal Slider
   - Show: Fields
   - All Slide content fields, but are hidden
   - Include Field Global:Drupal Slider Layers
   - Pulled the field variables from the list of REPLACEMENT VARIABLES (automatically listed based on the content fields pulled in) to make sure I'm referencing the correct machine names. *For reference you have to put the Drupal Slider Layers after (under) the fields in the list in order for the REPLACEMENT VARIABLES to detect them*.
   - Background Image = {{ field_slide_image }}
   - Layer 1 = {{ title }} and {{ body }}

The output shows a broken image icon instead of the background image, then it shows the text from the {{ title }} and {{ body }} fields.

If I manually add the image field (stop excluding from display) the image shows up, but not through the Slider.

So the problem is

1. Image file is not getting pulled or displaying in the Drupal Slider Layers.
2. Even though the View is set to **Format: Slideshow** it is showing as list

Am I missing a step or setting, or is Drupal Slider broken in Drupal 8?

Comment: Did you follow the installation section and installed its library?

Comment: The images still shows the broken image icon and the text layering doesn't show. It does, however go from one slide to the next and not the list view.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Can you check if you have the site base url correctly? https://x-team.com/blog/base_url-drupal-8/

Comment: If your image is broken, check the url, try opening it with browser. Perhaps it's a permission issue that is not allowing  your Drupal save image styled images in the files folder.